# std::vector of multiple wrappers containing std::function callbacks does not work

Tags: c++, c++11

I am coding a wrapper `MyTest` that is containing a std::function<> used for storing callback. 
The wrappers are contained in a std::vector `tests` of shared_ptr<>. 
emplace_back a single wrapper in the vector works, i.e. the std::function callback can be fired. If I have two objects in the vector, only the last object callback works.

Here are my classes:

```
typedef function<void(const uint64_t &)> CallBackFunc_t;

class MyWheel
{
private:
    class test
    {
    private:
        const CallBackFunc_t &callback;
    public:
        test(const CallBackFunc_t &cb);
        bool work();
    };

public:
    vector<shared_ptr<test>> tests;
    int addTest(const CallBackFunc_t &test_callback);
    void spin(void);

};


class MyTest
{
private:
    int handle = -1;
    MyWheel &wheel;
public:
    MyTest(MyWheel &whl);
    int setCallback(const CallBackFunc_t &callback);
};
```

And the source.

```
MyWheel::test::test(const CallBackFunc_t &cb) : callback(cb)
{

}

bool MyWheel::test::work()
{
    callback(0);
    return true;
}

int MyWheel::addTest(const CallBackFunc_t &test_callback)
{
    tests.emplace_back(new test(test_callback));
    return (int)(test.size()-1);
}

void MyWheel::spin(void)
{
    for(vector<shared_ptr<test>>::iterator test = tests.begin(); test != tests.end(); ++test)
    {
       (*test)->work();
    }
}

MyTest::MyTest(MyWheel &whl) : wheel(whl)
{

};

int MyTest::setCallback(const CallBackFunc_t &callback)
{
    if(handle < 0)
    {
        handle = wheel.addTest(callback);
    }
    return handle;
}
```

Usage:

```
MyWheel wh;
MyTest t1(wh);
MyTest t2(wh);

t1.setCallback([&](const uint64_t &e) {
   cout <<"1\r\n";
});

t2.setCallback([&](const uint64_t &e) {
   cout <<"2\r\n";
});

while(true)
{
   wh.spin();
}
```

I expect "1" and "2" to be printed when running, but only "2" is...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store callback by copy:

```
class test
{
private:
    CallBackFunc_t callback; // <---- make a copy of callback
public:
    test(const CallBackFunc_t &cb);
    bool work();
};
```

now you have undefined behaviour, because you are storing reference to callback which is destroyed at the end of this expression:

```
t1.setCallback([&](const uint64_t &e) {
   cout <<"1\r\n";
}); // it causes dangling reference
```

---

If you want to stay with reference to callback inside `test` you need to create them as Lvalues before calling `setCallback`:

```
std::function<void (const uint64_t& )> callback1 = [](const uint64_t &e)  {
   cout <<"1\r\n";
};
t1.setCallback(callback1);

std::function<void (const uint64_t& )> callback2 = [](const uint64_t &e)  {
   cout <<"2\r\n";
};
t2.setCallback(callback2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi rafix07 and thanks for the examples!
Yes, that did the trick, and adding & in the capture list made it possible to access variables where callback function was defined.

I.e.

```
bool var1 = false;
std::function<void (const uint64_t& )> callback1 = [&](const uint64_t &e)  {
   cout <<"1\r\n";
   var1 = true;
};
t1.setCallback(callback1);
```